# How can I simply serve static pages with child routes in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Maybe I am overcomplicating this, but the documentation isn't very clear to me. I am using Zend Framework 2 to serve some dynamic content, but I also have a few routes that are purely static HTML pages. Those static pages are all children of a parent route. For example:

```
/foo/bar
/foo/baz
/foo/cat
```

How can I just simply serve up these static pages if I already have a "FooController" I should add that /foo doesn't have a view itself, but all of the foo children do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to set up your route like this:

```
'foopage' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/foo/:action',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'My\Controller\Foo',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'constraints' => array(
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z]+'
        )
    ),        
)
```

Then inside your FooController simply create a couple of empty actions like `indexAction`, `fooAction`, `barAction`, `bazAction` and create the respective templates.

An alternative would be to use the Module of Matthew called [**PhlySimplePage**](https://github.com/weierophinney/PhlySimplePage)

Comment: So, I do indeed have to to add actions to my controller for every static page I want to load? That seems overly cumbersome. PhlySimplePage looks good, thanks.

Comment: That's the way the framework works ;) The alternative would be what PhlySimplePage does, using events to make actions obsolete.